# How much memory (in bytes) is allocated to `&'static str` in Rust?

Tags: rust

In this example:

```
enum BinaryTree<T> { 
       Empty,
       NonEmpty(Box<TreeNode<T>>),
}
fn binary_tree_size() {
    use std::mem::size_of;

    let word = size_of::<usize>();
 
    type Triple = (&'static str, BinaryTree<&'static str>, BinaryTree<&'static str>);
    assert_eq!(size_of::<Triple>(), 4 * word);
}
```

I understand that both `BinaryTree<&'static str>` inside `Triple` have a size of `usize` each (because the largest field size of the enum is a `Box`). So am I correct in inferring that `&'static str` is of size 2 * `usize`? I can't find how much memory is allocated to `&'static str` in the docs.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the [documentation of the `str` type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#representation). And yes, `size_of::<&str>() == 2 * size_of::<usize>()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every slice consists of 2 components: the pointer to the first byte of the slice and the length of the slice. To represent both pointer and length Rust is using `usize`. The `str` type is a slice, thus the `size_of::<&str>() == 2 * size_of::<usize>()`.